# How to cast Dataset<Row> columns to Non- Primitive Data Type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset<Row>` which has four columns in it out of four two columns are Non-Primitive Data Types `List<Long> and List<String>`.

```
  +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
  |    Id| value         |     time                                      |aggregateType  |
  +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
  |0001  |  [1.5,3.4,4.5]| [1551502200000,1551502200000,1551502200000] | Sum             |
  +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

I have an UDF3 which accepts three arguments and return a `Double` value `UDF3<String,List<Long>,List<String>,Double>`.

So when I call the UDF it throws an exception saying

**Error**

```
caused by java.lang.classcastexception scala.collection.mutable.wrappedarray$ofref cannot be cast to java.lang.List
```

But if I changed the types to `String` like `UDF3<String,String,String,Double>` its not complaining.

**Code which throws above Exception**

```
 UDF3<String,List<Long>,List<String>,Double> getAggregate = new UDF3<String,List<Long>,List<String>,Double>() {

 public Double call(String t1,List<Long> t2,List<String> t3) throws Exception {

 //do some process to return double

  return double;
  }

  sparkSession.udf().register("getAggregate_UDF",getAggregate, DataTypes.DoubleType);

  inputDS = inputDs.withColumn("value_new",callUDF("getAggregate_UDF",col("aggregateType"),col("time"),col("value")));
```

**Code after changing all the types to String**

```
 UDF3<String,String,String,Double> getAggregate = new UDF3<String,String,String,Double>() {

 public Double call(String t1,String t2,String t3) throws Exception {

 //code to convert t2 and t3 to List<Long> and List<String> respectively

 //do some process to return double

  return double;
  }

  sparkSession.udf().register("getAggregate_UDF",getAggregate, DataTypes.DoubleType);

  inputDS = inputDs.withColumn("value_new",callUDF("getAggregate_UDF",col("aggregateType"),col("time").cast("String"),col("value").cast("String")));
```

The above code works but with `String to List` conversion manually.

**Help Needed**

I) How to cast Non-Primitive Data Types `List<Long> and List<String>` in dataset to overcome `caused by java.lang.classcastexception scala.collection.mutable.wrappedarray$ofref cannot be cast to java.lang.List`

II) kindly suggest me if there is any workaround

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste your printSchema to let us know the actual data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UDF will always receive WrappedArray instances instead of List, because this is how they are stored by the engine.

You need to write something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

UDF3<String, WrappedArray<Long>, WrappedArray<String>, Double> myUDF = new UDF3<String, WrappedArray<Long>, WrappedArray<String>, Double> () {
      public Double call(String param1, WrappedArray<Long> param2, WrappedArray<String> param3) throws Exception {
        List<Long> param1AsList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(param1);
        List<String> param2AsList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(param2);

        ... do work ...

        return myDoubleResult;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @rluta, I have tried the UDF3 like above and it was throwing the Error mentioned above, so I have changed all the types to `String`. please have a look to the question I updated it now.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were using Scala. For java, you need to specifically use the WrappedArray class in the signature and the JavaConversions to recast as list. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. your solution helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example, you have to use WrappedArray to receive array and convert to list

```
 /*
     +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
     |    Id| value         |     time                                      |aggregateType  |
     +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
     |0001  |  [1.5,3.4,4.5]| [1551502200000,1551502200000,1551502200000] | Sum             |
     +------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+
     **/

    StructType dataSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {createStructField("Id", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                                                              createStructField("value",
                                                                                DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.DoubleType,
                                                                                                          false),
                                                                                false),

                                                              createStructField("time",
                                                                                DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.LongType,
                                                                                                          false),
                                                                                false),
                                                              createStructField("aggregateType",
                                                                                DataTypes.StringType,
                                                                                true),});

    List<Row> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add(RowFactory.create("0001",
                               Arrays.asList(1.5, 3.4, 4.5),
                               Arrays.asList(1551502200000L, 1551502200000L, 1551502200000L),
                               "sum"));
    Dataset<Row> example = spark.createDataFrame(data, dataSchema);
    example.show(false);

    UDF3<String, WrappedArray<Long>, WrappedArray<Double>, Double> myUDF = (param1, param2, param3) -> {

        List<Long> param1AsList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(param2);
        List<Double> param2AsList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(param3);

        //Example
        double myDoubleResult = 0;
        if ("sum".equals(param1)) {

            myDoubleResult = param2AsList.stream()
                                         .mapToDouble(f -> f)
                                         .sum();
        }

        return myDoubleResult;
    };

    spark.udf()
         .register("myUDF", myUDF, DataTypes.DoubleType);

    example = example.withColumn("new", callUDF("myUDF", col("aggregateType"), col("time"), col("value")));
    example.show(false);
```

You can get it from [github](https://github.com/howie/spark-java-example/blob/master/src/test/java/tw/howie/example/spark/ExampleOfWrappedArrayUDF.java)

Comment: Hi howie, I have a doubt on how to pass entire `Row` to UDF function in below code `inputDS = inputDs.withColumn("value_new",callUDF("getAggregate_UDF",//how to pass the entire Row here));`

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
-Syntax error insert ';' to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
-Syntax error insert '[]' to complete Dimension
-WrappedArray is a raw type. Reference to generic type WrappedArray<T> should be parameterized
-Syntax error on token "splitSeqUDF", AnnotationName expected after time token
-illegal modifier for parameter splitSeqUDF,onlu final is permitted